# Video not uploading to mysql database.Wheather the image and audio insert at the same video file field

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code for upload video but the video neither going to the folder nor to the database. But at the same video file field if You upload image or audio it's working and also i set the `upload_max_filesize` to 500M in php.ini. can any one suggest thank you in advance.

this is the code which i use to upload video.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{     
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $video=$_FILES['vid']['name'];
        $type=$_FILES['vid']['type'];
        $size=$_FILES['vid']['size'];
        $tempname=$_FILES['vid']['tmp_name'];
        $dir="uploadvideo/".$video;
        move_uploaded_file($tempname,"$dir");
$insert=mysql_query("insert into myblog(`video`) values ('$video')")or die(mysql_error());
      if($insert)     
      {
          echo "<script>alert('Inserted Succesful')</script>";


     }

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="file" class="tbl">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="vid" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `php.ini`

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M

upload_max_filesize = 2M

max_execution_time = 30

max_input_time = 60

memory_limit = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M

upload_max_filesize = 750M

max_execution_time = 5000

max_input_time = 5000

memory_limit = 1000M
```

Comment: Thank You @Damon.s it works only to increase the post_max_size.

Comment: still you cant upload your videos?

Comment: Yes it works i now can able to upload all kind of video. @Damon.s

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{     
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $video=$_FILES['vid']['name'];
    $type=$_FILES['vid']['type'];
    $size=$_FILES['vid']['size'];
    $tempname=$_FILES['vid']['tmp_name'];
    $dir="uploadvideo/".$video;
    move_uploaded_file($tempname,"$dir");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO myblog (`video`) VALUES ('".$video."')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($result)     
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Inserted Succesful')</script>";
    }
}
```